# We couldn’t get your developer license for Windows 8.1 - Error 0x8007000D unvalid data

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, registration

I've an error when I try to get my developer license with a live ID account.
I just want to develop a Windows 8.1 store app.

First I start Visual Studio 2013, create a new projet Windows 8.1 Universal.
A prompt dialog ask me to loggon with my LiveID (which is an enterprise developer account, paid 75€) then the following error append : "We couldn’t get your developer license for Windows 8.1 - Error 0x8007000D"
Same error with the PowerShell cmdlet : Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration

I already searched on differents topics but nothing is helping me.
I really need to activate the license cause the project began last week so I'm late...

Please help me to find a solution.

Regards, 
Armand.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an account-specific vendor support question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yor have to quit your domain and then activate your developer licence.
Once licence activated you can join your domain

Comment: I did and it works.
Thanks it was really helpful